# Spring XD REST Service

Tags: spring, rest

I would like to have a REST service to expose the data read and processed from Spring XD. Similar to the one in the Analytics Server.

For example I would like my own functions which can be exposed similar to Counters and be able to access the data from a web browser.

Is there any tutorial? I have searched and found that Spring Boot is the one but I am looking for help on how I integrate it with Spring XD.

Would be very helpful if someone can point me to the instructions on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger as a source with http-client as a processor processor to access any web browsers info regardless if it is a web service URL or not.

Moha.